# Is it possible for all the owners of a stock to gain or lose money at the same time?

Tags: investing, stocks

I might sound weird, but I want to know if there is a case where all the owners of a specific stock lose or gain money whether it is an up or down market?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

If the stock price is at an all-time high, everyone who owns the stock is 'in the money'. Of course, they won't actually realise a capital gain until they sell the stock. Similarly, if the stock becomes worthless (the company shuts down after declaring bankruptcy, etc.), everyone who owns the stock is out whatever they paid for the stock.

Comment: Thanks for the response and I think @Dheer explained it well.

Answer (score 2):

The Owners of stock keep changing with every Buy and Sell. Hence its theoritically possible that everyone makes or loses money. Say the price was $10 when everyone purchased the stock. If the stock is doing good and the markets are good, the stock will move up to $12. Everyone sells the stock to someone else. So all the Old owners have made $2. Now after some period of time, the stock / company is not doing so well, and the markets are bad, so the stock falls to $11, everyone sells. So all the current owners make a loss of $1.

However in normal market conditions, there are Owners who have purchased stock at different price points and have held it irrespective of whether the price has gone above their purchase price or below their purchase price.

Comment: Good point. I haven' thought of that way.

Comment: Don't confuse *trading* stocks with the stock market as a whole. Most entities who own stock in a company do so because it represents some portion of a (hopefully) profitable business, and makes money by doing useful things for people. Despite the flashy graphs, it's not just a game of watching some random numbers go up and down and betting on the outcome (though that is possible to do), and owners can make a ton of money from dividends without any trading activity.

Answer (score 1):

Take the case where a stock has just two owners, A and B, both at $10. One of them sells his shares to C, at $11.

Now B has made $1 in profit but is no longer an owner of the stock.

A hasn't sold anything but his shares are worth 10% more due to the last traded price printed.

C has bought shares at $11 and the price is $11, so technically he hasn't lost any money.

In a larger market, there are winners and losers every day on a single stock, but they may not remain owners of a stock. There could be days in which those that remain owners are all winners - say when a stock goes up to an all time high and all those that are currently owners have an average buy price lower than the last traded price. And the reverse applies too.

It is of course more complicated. Say you own a stock and let someone else "borrow" it for a short-selling opportunity (he sells it in the market). For each uptick in price, you win, the short seller loses, and the guy he sold it to also wins. A person that has a covered call on a stock is not a winner beyond a point. And so on.